# Build IndexSettings from two IndexSettings

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Using `org.elasticsearch.client:transport`, I was able to build index Settings from two Settings like that:
`Settings.builder().put(SETTINGS_1).put(SETTINGS_2).build()`

Is it possible to do the same with `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java` ?
Like that:
`new IndexSettings.Builder().settings(INDEX_SETTINGS_1).settings(INDEX_SETTINGS_2)`